# if no file selected, then return false, but not working

Tags: php

This is my upload class:

```
class UploadModel
{

    public static function upload()
    {

        if(empty($_FILES['image_upload']) || !isset($_FILES['image_upload'])){
            // Session::add('feedback_negative', Text::get('FEEDBACK_IMAGE_UPLOAD_ERROR'));
        return false;
        }

    $image = new Image($_FILES['image_upload']);

    if($image){
    $upload = $image->upload(); 

    if($upload){
        //Everything is OK!
        Session::add('feedback_positive', Text::get('FEEDBACK_IMAGE_UPLOAD_SUCCESS'));            
        return true;
    }else{
        //Session::add('feedback_negative', Text::get('FEEDBACK_IMAGE_UPLOAD_ERROR'));
        // For security reasons maybe the above is the way to go? (no super obvious error message)
        Session::add('feedback_negative', $image["error"]);
        return false;
    }
}

}
}
```

But for some reason the first if statement is not working (is what i believe anyway).

I thought that the following if statement would "stop" the execution of the class, returning false.

```
if(empty($_FILES['image_upload']) || !isset($_FILES['image_upload'])){
    // Session::add('feedback_negative', Text::get('FEEDBACK_IMAGE_UPLOAD_ERROR'));
return false;
}
```

But it doesent. I get the following error message

> Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in ...
>
> Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in ...
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at

On a virtual ubuntu box, the app continues and at least gives me the error from `Session::add('feedback_negative', $image["error"]);` (Image is not found)

But on my dev MAMP server (mac os) the app halts at the previous error message.

And again, i think it is the first if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_FILES` is always populated even if no file was selected.

Check the size to see if there is actually a file:

```
if ($_FILES['image_upload']['size'] > 0) {
```

You can also check the file name:

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_upload']['tmp_name'])) {
```

If you do a `var_dump($_FILES);` you will get a better understanding of the data you're receiving.

Comment: Tanks! i did as you said, had a look at the array structure of _FILES. I went with the operator <= for size. Leave a comment if thats a bad idea

Comment: Ah yes, you're checking if the file is NOT uploaded. That's fine, then, though `== 0` might be more sane (it should never be < 0)